# Exemplo de menu responsivo com angular 5+

Tags: angular

peguei um projeto em angular e o menu é responsivo, porém o programador não fez com angular, não criou um componente, ele fez separado com javascript e "acoplou" no projeto. Acredito que seja uma gambiarra. É possível fazer um menu responsivo usando componente em angular? Qual seria a forma mais elegante de fazer?

Tipo esse menu usando componente com angular: http://osvaldas.info/examples/drop-down-navigation-touch-friendly-and-responsive/?work#

Comment: acredito que vc teria que chamar o document do angular e fazer em javascript puro, ate o conhecimento que sei em angular seria assim, não sei se o animate do angular serveria para isso

Comment: agora ja não sei se estou falando demais, mais o angular quando vc complia ele, te leva para o javascript puro ;)

Comment: feio seria com $jquery

Comment: vc pd fazer em css puro tbm

Comment: por não ter o click vc poderia fazer com css https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

Comment: @Willian Como assim por não ter click?

Comment: seguinte, pois se tivesse que clicar no menu para ele abrir, vc teria um evento de click, mais como não tem esse evento vc nao precisa do js, pode fazer ele full css

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, você pode utilizar o Angular Material que a biblioteca oficial do Angular para componentes de tela.

Nela entre diversos componentes, existe o componente `mat-menu` que é justamente um menu estilo dropdown pronto, como aparentemente você procura.

A documentação do componente, assim como exemplos, se encontram no link abaixo:
https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview

Para adicionar o angular material como dependência de seu projeto você deve seguir as seguintes instruções:
https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Espero ter ajudado.